# Crossfading between label colors over time in tkinter?

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

What would be a way I could implement a fade over time between two colors for the background of a label in Tkinter? *I want the color of a label for my timer to change as it counts down.* These are the snippets I'm working with currently, (to clarify what I'm doing).

```
…

labelcolor = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (0, 0, 0)

…

def pomodoro(self, remaining = None):
    self.button.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.labelcolor = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (200, 32, 32)
    self.label.configure(bg = self.labelcolor)
    if remaining is not None:
        self.remaining = remaining

    if self.remaining <= 0:
        self.label.configure(text="Time's up!")
        self.breakcommand
    else:
        self.label.configure(text= time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(self.remaining))) #Integer to 'Minutes' and 'Seconds'
        self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
        self.after(1000, self.pomodoro)

…

self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Pick One", width=12, font="Helvetica 32", fg = "white", bg = self.labelcolor )

…
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the problem? Do you not know how to change the background color of a label, or do you not know how to create a range of colors, or is there something else you don't understand?

Comment: @Bryan I didn't understand how to do the fading its self from a math stand point and from there create a usable function for fading between any two colors based on a timer. Sorry for my question being unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little code I hacked together to create a colorbar with a gradient.  I don't know if it will be useful to you, but...It works...

```
import Tkinter as tk

def cinterp(x1,x2,x,c1,c2):
    """
    interpolate two colors.  c1 and c2 are 3-tuples of rgb values -- 
    e.g. (0,0,255)

    x1,x2 and x are used to determine the interpolation constants.
    """
    s1=float(x-x1)/(x2-x1)
    s2=1.-s1
    return [max(0, min(255, int(s1 * i + s2 * j))) for i, j in zip(c1, c2)]

root=tk.Tk()
cvs=tk.Canvas(root,width=100,height=50)
cvs.grid(row=0,column=0)
width=int(cvs['width']) 
height=int(cvs['height'])
for i in range(width):
   fill=cinterp(0,width,i,(255,0,0),(255,255,255))
   fs="#%02x%02x%02x"%(fill[0],fill[1],fill[2])
   cvs.create_rectangle(i,1,i+1,height,fill=fs,width=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Of course, you may want to keep a handle on your rectangles so you can change the colors later, and you could probably do this more efficiently too, but this might be a good starting point.

**EDIT**

```
import Tkinter as tk

def cinterp(x1,x2,x,c1,c2):
    s1=float(x-x1)/(x2-x1)
    s2=1.-s1
    return [max(0, min(255, int(s1 * i + s2 * j))) for i, j in zip(c1, c2)]

root=tk.Tk()
cvs=tk.Label(root,text="Hello")
c2=(255,0,0)
c1=(255,255,255)
def updateCVS(dt,timeleft,deltat):
    timeleft=timeleft-dt
    fill=cinterp(0,deltat,deltat-timeleft,c1,c2)
    fs="#%02x%02x%02x"%(fill[0],fill[1],fill[2])
    cvs.configure(bg=fs)
    if(timeleft>0):
        timeleft=timeleft-dt
        cvs.after(int(dt*1000),updateCVS,dt,timeleft,deltat)

cvs.grid(row=0,column=0)
b=tk.Button(root,text="push me",command=lambda : updateCVS(.2,5,5))
b.grid(row=1,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This would be a lot cleaner in a class, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This is useful for other reasons, but not what I'm looking for. I want to change the canvas background color over time as my counter counts down. I reworded my question to hopefully make what I want to do clearer.

Comment: @RyanHasse That's easy too.  Just take the function cinterp, and call it to update your label/canvas/whatever re-registering in an `after` call.  I don't have time to post a real solution now, but I can in the morning if you haven't figured it out yet.